# Matlab arrayfun mapping using two arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, dictionary

How would I go about mapping the values of TWO arrays to a function and returning the result as an array?

```
arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr2 = [1, 4, 5];

val= arrayfun(@(x) func(arr, arr2))

function val = func(x, y)
// Takes in two arrays, and does a double 'for' loop
// for all values in x, for all values in y, do x*y
```

So basically I would end up with an array of X Y val:

```
1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3    3    <- X values
1    4    5    1    4    5    1    4    5    <- Y values
1*1, 1*4, 1*5, 2*1, 2*4, 2*5, 3*1, 3*4, 3*5  <- X*Y values
```

Thanks.

EDIT - Updated desired output array

Comment: you want the resultant array to store the product?

Comment: Not exactly, there will be a different formula in `func`. I am just using the product as an example.

Comment: well this could be implemented with nested for loops,which you already know,what's the difficulty that you're facing?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I'm very new to Matlab and have no idea how I would go about producing the resulting array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
             arr=[1,2,3];
             arr2=[1,4,5];
             product=zeros(1,9);
             index=1;
             for i=1:length(arr)
               for j=1:length(arr2)
                  product(index)=arr(i)*arr2(j);
                  index=index+1;
               end
             end
```

try the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed this way:

```
res = arrayfun(@(i) arr(i).*arr2,1:numel(arr),'UniformOutput',0);
final_res = cat(2,res{:});
```

I hope this helps.